# Как сделать, чтобы при передаче в функцию именованных аргументов, имена этих аргументов были в переменной?

Tags: python

Как сделать, чтобы при передаче в функцию именованных аргументов, имена этих аргументов были в переменной?

Примерно так:

```
x = 'name'
def a(name = None) : pass
    
a(x = 'John')
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Вы можете использовать [kwargs](https://pythontips.com/2013/08/04/args-and-kwargs-in-python-explained/) pattern:

```
def test(**kwargs):
    if kwargs:
        for k,v in kwargs.items():
            print('{}:\t{}'.format(k,v))

In [279]: test(first_name='John', last_name='Doe')
last_name:      Doe
first_name:     John
```

или так:

```
In [282]: parms = {'par1': 'val1', 'par2': 'val2'}

In [283]: test(**parms)
par2:   val2
par1:   val1
```